# Referencing a global object in a Vue2 child component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a problem referencing, updating and accessing a global object
defined as "Vue.prototype.$redirectObj"
in a child component.

```
main.js

Vue.prototype.$auth0Instance = new Auth0CLS();

Vue.prototype.$redirectObj = {
  path: "/foo/bar"
}
------------------------------------------------------
component_sign_up.vue

<div @click="signInWithAuth0">Log in</div>
export default {

data() {
  methods: {
      signInWithAuth0() {
        this.$redirectObj.path = "/xxx/yyy";
        this.$auth0Instance.login();
      }
  }
------------------------------------------------------
component_callback.vue

  mounted() {
      this.$auth0Instance.handleRedirect( $redirectObj );
  },
------------------------------------------------------

class Auth0CLS {

  handleRedirect(_redirectObj) {
    console.log( Vue.prototype.$redirectObj === _redirectObj ) 
    // true

    console.log( Vue.prototype.$redirectObj.path ) 
    // "/foo/bar"
  }
}
```

Can somebody explain to me why 
Vue.prototype.$redirectObj.path
does not contain "/xxx/yyy" ?
What am I missing?

Comment: It is prototype everywhere in my code. Cody Ｇ. Just a mistype in the post. I use console.log. The problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You simply not accessing the same thing. `Vue.prototype.$redirectObj` is bound to the prototype and will be used as default value in each Vue instance at creation. `this.$redirectObj` is bound to the current Vue instance used. See this short example :

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.prototype.test = 'static';

const vue = new Vue({
  created() {
    console.log("What's my test value : " + this.test);
    this.test = 'instance';
  }
});

console.log(Vue.prototype.test, vue.test, Vue.prototype.test === vue.test);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

If you want to pass through a global object. You can use a getter and a setter :

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

let test = 'static';
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, 'test', {
  get: () => test,
  set: val => { test = val }
});



const vue = new Vue({
  created() {
    console.log("What's my test value : " + this.test);
    this.test = 'changed';
  }
});

console.log(Vue.prototype.test, vue.test, Vue.prototype.test === vue.test);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Anyway, you must be very cautious when playing with prototypes. If you can, you'd far better switch to ES modules to separate your Auth logic and simply import it where you need it.

Comment: I tried it. The value is still 'static' inside of "handleRedirect" function.

Comment: What did you try exactly ?